# NSMutablearray define init issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, arrays, nsmutablearray

i have the following line of code

```
NSMutableArray *marray = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"4", @"1", @"9", nil]mutableCopy];
```

and i want to replace it  with the following line

```
NSMutableArray  *marray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:garr];
```

where garr is global array from global method

the problem is that the code works fine when calling the first line but when using the second one the code crash , appreciate ur help and ideas thanks , iknow that the first one is NSArray but the garr variable source is NSMutable array
 here is the code for garr

```
     garr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        [garr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: arc4random()%200]];
```

here is the error msg
console error:2012-09-02 14:46:42.976 sort_alg[1561:207] -[NSCFNumber UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b1a170 2012-09-02 14:46:42.978 sort_alg[1561:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFNumber UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b1a170' *** Call stack at first throw: –

this is the code that generates the end value

```
NSString *element; 
NSEnumerator *iterator = [marray objectEnumerator];
while ((element = [iterator nextObject]) != nil)
printf("%s ", [element UTF8String]);
printf("\n");
[marray release];   // array needs to be released! 
[pool release];
```

thanks

Comment: Error message, crash log, stacktrace, core dump?

Comment: Your first array contains strings, the second one numbers. It looks like some other code that you're not showing here, expects the array to still contain strings...

Comment: @OracleOracle: Please update your question, don't paste the error message in the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem lies in `printf("%s ", [element UTF8String]);`.

`NSNumber` has no `UTF8String` method, only a `stringValue`. You can't `printf` it either, but you can `NSLog("%@", [element stringValue])`, or `NSLog("%d", [element intValue])` if you know it's an int.

Comment: By the way, instead of going all the way to instanciating an enumerator, you can just use fast enumeration: `for (NSNumber *num in marray) { NSLog("%@", [num stringValue]); }`.

Comment: don't use equal '=' for comparison of objets. use `isEqual:`

Comment: Hey, you could `printf("%s", [[element stringValue] UTF8String]);`

Comment: All went fine many thanks the issue is with the NSstring and Nsnumber with thanks